# Access an mp3 in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am playing a song in Cocos2D iphone using this line.

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"song.mp3"];
```

Suppose the mp3 is 1 min long, I want to play the song from 10 sec to 20 sec. Is it possible in Cocos2D iphone. Please help.

Comment: the playEffect method is intended to play only short effect sounds, for background music there are different methods

Comment: Can you please explain what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to "play the song from 10 sec to 20 sec" using the audio engine of cocos2d-iphone (which is named CocosDeshion).

[SimpleAudioEngine](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_simple_audio_engine.html) is the main interface to CocosDeshion. Basically in cocos2d development we use audio files in two way - sound effect (short) and background music (long and usually loop). playEffect: is for the short ones, while playBackgroundMusic: and playBackgroundMusic:loop: is for the long ones. preloadBackgroundMusic: provides you the ability to cache the music in memory to avoid lag while playing, since they are often in compressed format.

As you can see in the documentation of SimpleAudioEngine (link above), there isn't such method for you to play a part of an audio file. Even the underlying class CDAudioManager doesn't support this.

I suggest to extract the 0:10 - 0:20 part as a separate audio file. But if you have a special reason to do this, you may want to use audio playback interfaces (such as AVAudioPlayer) in iOS SDK directly. Please refer to: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html